# Why place any identifier in conditional statements without giving any condition?

Tags: c

```
  struct Node *prevX = NULL, *currX = *head_ref; 
  while (currX && currX->data != x) 
 { 
   prevX = currX; 
   currX = currX->next; 
 }
```

Why was currX placed here? How can it affect the outcome?

Comment: "Why was currX placed here?" --> certainly looks like _null pointer_ detection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important point about the condition `(currX && currX->data != x)` is that `&&` will "short circuit", that is to say, if `currX` is false (meaning, the pointer is null) the right hand half will not be evaluated, since the entire expression must be false.

`if (ptr && ptr->foo)` is a common pattern used to protect against dereferencing a null pointer.

Answer (score 5):

`while (currX)`  tests the truthiness of `currX`. It's effectively short for `while (0!=currX)`.

Comment: Or one could just as easily say that `while (0 != currX)` is *long* for `while (currX)`.  One should remember that in C, relational expressions evaluate to integers, so conditional statements having relational expressions as their conditions are just testing the truthiness of the expression's integer result.